# Python Regex Why does it not find all double words?

Tags: python, regex, findall

I need to match double words but my regex is not working correctly.

```
L = "let's s?,play%3with,1symbols88,/symbols"
pattern = r'(\b\S+\b)[\d\s\.,-?\)\(!\/]+\b\1\b'
r = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
print(re.findall(r, L))

# Outputs: ['s']
# Expected: ['s','symbols']
```

https://regex101.com/r/frz8kQ/3

Comment: Digits are word characters, thus there is no boundary between `symbols` and `88`

Comment: What is a "double word"?  Why would you expect your solution to work?

Comment: @SebastianProske Yes that's it ^^ I totally forgot about how the word boundries '\b' are defined

Comment: So, remove them and use [`r'(\S+)[\d\s.,?)(!/-]+\b\1\b'`](https://regex101.com/r/frz8kQ/5). And put the `-` at the end of the character class as `[,-?]` forms a range.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah was able to figure it out, after Sebastian remark... Thanks a lot though

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Putting the '-' at the end is also something I missed. Makes me feel silly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a more basic regex with a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import re
from collections import Counter
text = "let's s?,play%3with,1symbols88,/symbols"

word_pattern = re.compile('[a-z]+', re.I)
word_counter = Counter(re.findall(word_pattern, text))
print([word for word, counter in word_counter.items() if counter > 1])
# ['symbols', 's']
```

Comment: Way more elegant then what I had in mind, nice solution

Comment: One remark: it will extract words that are repeated anywhere inside the string, not those words that are separated with a specific set of characters. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/i5d3T1), `s` is still extracted though the [original regex does not match it](https://regex101.com/r/frz8kQ/6).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I don't know if the original regex was an attempt or the description of the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Another one-liner using `re.split()` function and `Counter` subclass:

```
import collections, re

L = "let's s?,play%3with,1symbols88,/symbols"
print([i for i,c in collections.Counter(re.split(r'[\d\W]+', L)).items() if c > 1])
```

The output:

```
['s', 'symbols']
```